Should one stick to 1NF (and higher NF) rules for SQL even while using ORMs?
I am currently making a database in MySQL using the SQLAlchemy ORM. I followed the principles of 1NF until this point (atomised Data, no redundancy) but now I am tempted to add a few useful (though technically redundant columns).
1NF would prescribe using a Foreign Key Column in the Children table which points to an entry in the Parent table. However, for the sake of my front-end tasks, I was also thinking of adding a "Children" column in my Parent table that has the primary keys of all the children to that entry [Note that each parent has multiple children so this "Children" Column in the Parent Table essentially has a list. This will help me as I can simply use "parentXYZ.children" instead of having to query the Children table to get a list of all children to parentXYZ]. The "relationship" feature (paired with "back_populates") in SQLAlchemy even seems to suggest this is optimal.
Will this have any major issues down the line if I can be sure I will be using the same ORM forever?
I have just begun reading up on SQL so apologies if this question is trivial.
Resources I read through already:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form


to be honest, as long as we don't understand the logic behind our app we can not give an advice the children column would only help if you had one children only, if that is the case why do you need the children table in the first place

@nbk In my database, one parent has multiple children. Hence it is a one-to-many relationship that I am trying to make easier to traverse by saving the list of primary keys of the children to that parent in a column named "Children" in my Parent Table. Apologies for the omission.

Using an ORM should have nothing to do with deciding how normalized you make your database. They are decoupled concepts. It's like asking if you should put a bandaid on your finger because your knee hurts. I haven't used SQLAlchemy in a while, but most ORMs let you define an association between your tables so that you can still directly access parentXYZ.children without having to redundantly store those children fields in the parent.

@nbk and J.D. Thank you for your inputs

Normalization has two purposes in the real world, as opposed to the textbook world):  (1) ease of changing a value in only one place; (2) performance.  Show us the CREATE TABLEs
